# pgfkeys - storing today's date with pgfplotstablenew, pgfplotstablesave

Tags: pgfplotstable, pgfkeys

I'm working on making a simple tool to generate burn down reports/track task progress; this is my first foray into more complicated table manipulation so there's probably something pretty basic I'm not understanding. Hopefully someone wiser can set me straight :-)

I can create a new table and get today's date into it. It displays correctly when typeset (albeit duplicated and with extra commas). When I output that table to a file (`output.dat`), what is stored isn't the date, but `\today`. That's likely due to using `create col/set`.

My guess is that the "save" functionality isn't applying any typesetting to the data, so what I *actually* want is to store the `YYYY-MM-DD` date string to the table instead of `\today`. I've tried multiple methods of storing today's date into the table (based on the `pgfkeys`/`pgfplotstable` documentation), but am evidently going about it the wrong way.

What's the proper way to get this to format as a date when saving to an output file? Any assistance would be appreciated!

Here's my MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime}
    \renewcommand{\dateseparator}{-}

    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

    \begin{document}

    The current date is: \today

    \pgfplotstablenew[
        columns={Date},%
        create on use/Date/.style={create col/set={\today}, date type={\year-\month-\day}},%
    ]{1}\datestable

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[columns/Date/.style={string type}]{\datestable}

    \pgfplotstablesave[
        col sep=comma,%
        columns={Date},%
        columns/Date/.style={string type},%
    ]{\datestable}{output.dat}

    \end{document}
```

Contents of output.dat:

```
Date,
\today ,
\today ,
```

Comment: I ended up resolving my issue using

Answer (score 1):

I ended up resolving my problem by using

```
    create on use/Date/.style={create col/set/.expanded={{\isodate}}, date type},
```

This allows the set value to be expanded prior to storage.